# Should I separate websites for blog and business?

Tags: freelance-websites

I am a freelancer for web-development and I have currently 3 customers  but no own homepage.

I want to create a blog in English. The main reasons for that are given in this [short talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI-TDIoV_uw&t=315s).

Secondly, I would like to create a page where my customer can log in and use a ticket system and where I can advertise myself.

Now, since I am from Germany I am thinking about using a domain like ***my-name.de***  which contains my blog and my business like this:

[image]

I only want to offer my blog in English to prevent writing each post twice. Thus if blog and business would share the same domain together, I would do everything in English. Here is what I don't like about the idea:

- I would use a ***.de*** domain for English content only.
- If I want to write something about me in German too, but provide my Blog only in English language, then my site is inconsistent.

On the other hand, I could separate blog (***myBlog.com***) and business (***my-name.de***).

This would have the advantages that

- Blog would be only in English (.com domain)
- My business would be only in German (.de domain)

but it has the disadvantages that:

- I would need two buy separate domains and SSL certificates
- I would need somehow two distinct logos for the pages
- I would need to invent some random blog name

I am just not sure which way to go. Also, the blog would be for other developer, so I am not sure if this would make sense because my 3 customers so far have no developing-background at all.

Any recommendations which way is the best to go here? Or should I maybe create a blog & business domain in English like that: ***my-name.com*** ?

Comment: I'm uncertain anyone else could make this decision for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two main URLs that I share with people: my blog, and my "professional" website. They use the same certificate, issued by my proxy, Cloudflare (not affiliated, just like them).

I recommend separating it out. Your blog can potentially include contributions from other users, especially if it gets to be a bigger blog! It also helps having different personas to be known as - the Founder of BigBlog Company, and as the great Adam of Adam Portfolios! It gives you a separation of responsibilities, and allows for leniency one way or the other if you decide to go full time into only one (or none) of the two sites.

Having a `.com` for most people means English-speaking people are welcome. If you're blog is just in English, that would help. If you want to only work with German clients, then keeping `adam.de` would be beneficial, as users going to a `.de` domain are expecting it to be in German.

Again, the SSL issue is a non-issue if you have a proxy (i.e. Cloudflare), or if you use Let's Encrypt for your certificates. They are both free for small to medium sites.